# Selective POCO properties

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, poco, dto

Lets say I have the classes listed below that are used to pass data to a client through a web service (classes are simplified):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Sales> CustomerSales 
    {
        get { /*code to return list of customersales */ }
    }
    public double TotalSalesAmount 
    {
        get { /*code that return total sales amount for customer*/ }
    }
    public double AverageSalesPerMonth
    {
        get { /*code that return average sales amount per month for customer*/ }
    }
}

public class Sales
{
    public int SalesId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime SalesDate { get; set; }
    public double SalesAmount { get; set; }
}
```

The question I have is regarding the two properties:

```
    public double TotalSalesAmount 
    {
        get { /*code that return total sales amount for customer*/ }
    }
    public double AverageSalesPerMonth
    {
        get { /*code that return average sales amount per month for customer*/ }
    }
```

Sometimes the client only will only need the Customer information i.e. *CustomerId* and *Name*, and then sometimes it would require *CustomerId*, *Name* and *TotalSalesAmount* or a combination thereof and so forth. What would be the best practice regarding this. I found a few discussions on this topic and the following suggestions was made:

- Create a DTO for each scenario (this would mean that I will end up with 100's of DTO's as the example is simplified)
- Create a separate method on service for each calculations and execute method as needed (this would mean that lots of service calls would be made)
- Leave the properties in the classes as above (this would mean plenty of overhead - some calculations might be very resource intensive - that is not required)

I am sure that there is not a silver bullet for this, but would like to know what the best approach would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Luu - in general - but I'd use enum instead of bool flags - like:

```
public Customer GetCustomerInformation(int customerId, LevelOfDetail detail 
  = LevelOfDetail.All)
{
  var customer = new Customer { CustomerId = customerId };
  customer.TotalSalesAmount = detail.HasFlag(LevelOfDetail.TotalSalesAmount) ? CalculateTotalSales(customerId) : null;
  // etc
  return customer;
}

[Flags]
public enum LevelOfDetail : int
{
  TotalSalesAmount = (1 << 0),
  AverageSalesPerMonth = (1 << 1),
  All = TotalSalesAmount | AverageSalesPerMonth
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why bit shift? Why not simply set TotalSalesAmount = 0, or AverageSalesPerMonth = 1 in your enum?  Perhaps I'm wrong but it seems to take away from readability.

Comment: @JamesShaw - its a matter of taste. IMHO it looks better when you have lot of them (1 << 17) is way more readable than 131072.

Comment: This would be the cleanest and best solution for my scenario. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a single method, something like:

```
[Route("api/customers/{customerId:int}")]
public Customer GetCustomerInformation(int customerId, bool includeTotalSales, bool includeAverageSalesMonth)
{
    var customer = new Customer { CustomerId = customerId };
    customer.TotalSalesAmount = includeTotalSales ? CalculateTotalSales(customerId) : null;
    // etc
}
```

I assumed you're using Web API 2, but you would change it for whatever you're using. That way you would have one DTO, one call to the service, and no overhead. Would that work for your application?

edit: The caller would call something like `http://url:port/api/customers/111111?includeTotalSales=true&includeAveragesSalesMonth=false`.